# Cyclic ping in another thread + updating UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I'm implementing cyclic ping functionality which output should be reflected in UI button's enable status (i.e. when ping result != success, button should be disabled). I'm using WPF with MVVM model so I'm not interacting with controls from the code, but using bindings and notification mechanisms.

The problem is the following:

- I'm starting the application with network ok
- Button is grayed out
- I click somewhere in the UI area and the button is immediately active
- Now I disconnect network cable - the button keeps its state
- I click somewhere in the UI area - the button is immediately inactive

And so on. So the change in value of datapoint storing connection status isn't reflected in UI change - only when UI view is refreshed. I'm using the same notification mechanism in my whole application and it works fine.

I also tried to call ping just once in constructor of DB class and then the button on the screen goes active when my network is on while starting up application and inactive when network is broken. So the notification mechanism works.

Here's code which pings the station:

```
public sealed class DB
{
    Action _update= null;
    Ping _ping;
    Thread thread;
    static bool result;
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter<PingReply> _pingAwaiter;
    MachineState machineState;

    private DB() //Constructor
    {
        machineState = GlobalData.Instance.gMachineState;  //GlobalData is a Singleton

        _ping = new Ping();
        _update= Update;

        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CyclicTest));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void CyclicTest()
    {
        while (true)
        {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        _pingAwaiter = _ping.SendPingAsync(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 10, 10, 1, 11 }), 100).GetAwaiter();
        _pingAwaiter.OnCompleted(Update);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateConnectionStatus()
    {
        if (_pingAwaiter.GetResult().Status = IPStatus.Success)
            result = true;
        else
            result = false;

        machineState.DBLinkActive = result;
    }
}
```

Here's code of data model's property which I'm trying to update

```
public class MachineState : ObservableObject
{
    bool _dbLinkActive;
    public bool DBLinkActive
    {
        get => _dbLinkActive;
        set
            {
            if (_dbLinkActive == value)
                return;

            _dbLinkActive = value;

             NotifyPropertyChanged();
             }
    }
}
```

Here's NotifyPropertyChanged method of ObservableObject abstract class:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And here's code which is responsible for setting button's enable status (predicate)

```
public sealed class UnfinishedOrdersVM : ObservableObject
{
    private MachineState _machineStateData; //this is the same object as in DB class

    private bool CanRefreshOrders()
        {
            return _machineStateData.DBLinkActive;
        }
}
```

Why is that happening?

I know already, that threading is probably the issue. If I put MessageBox before `_dbLinkActive = value;` line in the public property I get multiple MessageBoexes showing up one after another - because it stops execution of calling thread and having many of them showing up proves there're many threads raised.

I also tried to change `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke` in `NotifyPropertyChanged` method, but same result.

Comment: You could replace all of this code if you used `async/await` and `await Task.Delay()` in a loop. If the async method was called by the UI thread, after each `await` you'd be back in the UI thread, allowing you to modify any UI element.

Comment: Multithreading is definally not the cause, because binding engine is designed work in multithreading enviroment. You need to put your view's code around the issuing button for diagnosis.

Comment: Notify propertychanged is only going to work if raised on the Ui thread. Looks like you're raising it on a different thread to ui. I agree with panagiotis Async await and task delay would be simpler. And would work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I've worked with the code and it turns out that the problem lies within CanRefreshOrders predicate which is bound to the button. I connected button's Content to connectionion status value within the same viewmodel and it works, i,e. the button changes its text depending on the connection status - but the button's enable status changes only after interaction with the UI. So the question is now about refreshing button predicate, not about pinging. BTW, NotifyPropertyChanged uses Invoke method, so we're sure that event will be raised within UI task.

Comment: Hi again, after further investigations I've noticed that described case is not happening as soon as I switch to x86 version. Compiling the code as 64-bit makes this behaviour happen. Weird thing